# Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() while sqlsrv dll's are loaded

Tags: php, sql-server

i am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() when i try to connect to database with this code and both dll's are present:

```
<?php
$serverName = "LOZANOVSKITLT\SQLEXPRESS";    
$connectionInfo = array( "Muzicari"=>"Bend");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  //here it fails
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Below in the google drive link you will see screenshots for better information

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

System Manufacturer: Acer

Memory: 4096MB RAM

System Model: Aspire 5741

32bit WAMP installation

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_B7w46v8TbWTkZPdWVkTml4VFk&usp=sharing

Comment: Did you restart the server after you installed the DLL's?

Comment: i restarted WAMP after that the machine

Comment: It's Windows environment, did you [registered](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249873) the DLLs for use?

Comment: Also, did you inserted the correct `extension` line on your `php.ini` file?

Comment: just tried to register the dll's, but it says "the file does not have program associated with it for performing the action, please install a program...." etc

Comment: all extensions are inserted correctly, and are ticked when you open wamp in tray

Comment: One more question, is your `extension_dir =` correctly pointing to your extensions directory?

Comment: Anyway, try using a [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-odbc.php) instead and see if it helps.

Comment: yes it is pointing to correct extension